# C# MongoDB multiple similar records

Tags: mongodb

I have just started using MongoDB and have a question... how do I do the following:

```
var testrec = new TestClass
{
  Name = "John",
  Address = "10 Here St",
  RecordType = "A"
};

db.Save(testrec);

testrec.RecordType = "B";
db.Save(testrec);
```

I want the second save to save as a new document so there should be 2 documents with the same details except for the RecordType.

What seems to happen is it just overrides the first document with the second.

Can someone please let me know.

Thanks
Dean

Comment: Are you using a C# interface or the Mongo Javascript shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to new up another Id and it will insert instead of updating. Here is a complete example:

```
using System;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace MongoTest
{
    class TestClass{
        public string Name;
        public string Address;
        public string RecordType;
        public ObjectId Id;
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            var server = client.GetServer();
            var db = server.GetDatabase("test");
            var collection = db.GetCollection("test");

            var testrec = new TestClass
            {
                Name = "John",
                Address = "10 Here St",
                RecordType = "A",
                Id = new ObjectId()
            };

            collection.Save(testrec);
            testrec.Id = new ObjectId();
            testrec.RecordType = "B";
            collection.Save(testrec);
            testrec.Id = new ObjectId();
            testrec.RecordType = "C";
            collection.Save(testrec);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you save the first document, it gets assigned an `_id`.

When you save a document with an existing `_id`, this is an update.

To insert a new document, either copy all fields (without the `_id`) into a new data structure, or unset the `_id` that was generated before.